# How to add an AAD group with datawrite and dataread permissions to an Azure DB through PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure SQL Server with an SQL database. I would like to add an AAD Group with datawrite and dataread permissions to this database through PowerShell.

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a user to a role is usually accomplished with SQL Statements. This is how this would be done with SQL.

```
CREATE USER [group name]
FROM external provider
DEFAULT_SCHEMA dbo
```

Once the user has been added, you can then add them to a group by issuing the following statements;

```
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [group_name]
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [group_name]
```

Note, within SSMS, you must be in the context of the database you want to add the user to. Azure SQL does not support USE statements, so ensure you selected the correct database.

To do it through powershell, you would probably want to use the following CmdLet, [Add-RoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/add-rolemember?view=sqlserver-ps), but I have not used these CmdLets with Azure SQL Server before.

This is one way to add users to a SQL database via Powershell;

```
$Instance = $ENV:AzureSQLServer + ".database.windows.net"

$Query = "CREATE USER [$ENV:AdUser] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"
$ConnString = "Server=" + $Instance + ";Database=master;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=" + $Env:SqlAdminUser + ";Password=" + $Env:SqlAdminPass + ";Trusted_Connection=false;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"

Invoke-SQlCmd -ConnectionString $ConnString -Query $Query
```

We use this script in a PowerShell task in Jenkins to add users to databases. The Statements could be modified to also add the users to the appropriate roles as well.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to set AAD Group as AAD admin for your SQL database.

With this scenario, you can use [**`Set-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqlserveractivedirectoryadministrator?view=azurermps-6.3.0):

```
Set-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DisplayName "DBAs" -ObjectId "40b79501-b343-44ed-9ce7-da4c8cc7353b"
```

**Result:**

```
ResourceGroupName ServerName DisplayName ObjectId 
----------------- ---------- ----------- -------- 
ResourceGroup01   Server01   DBAs        40b79501-b343-44ed-9ce7-da4c8cc7353b
```

**NOTE:**

*You can only set the AAD Group with securtiy enabled.*

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: No, this is not what i wanted. I already know how to set an aad group or user as sql admin. I need to set an aad group or user as a user for a sql database.

Comment: Hi @STORM , Sorry for that. But I think it is also another solution for memebers in AAD group to access the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to create an ADD group using e. g. the [`New-AzureADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet that is part of the [AzureAD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).

Then you have to assign the desired role to your desired resource (e. g. the SQL DB Contributor role to your DB Server) using the [`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-6.3.0) cmdlet.

Further reading: [Manage role-based access control with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell)

Comment: Ok thank you Martin. I understand that this is the way how to assign it to a SQL Server. But how to do it when i want to give access to a dedicated sql database?

Comment: Good point, I don't see the IAM tab on the database level - only on the server level. Not sure whether this is possible